# Convert a MOSCOW ML type to HASKELL

Tags: haskell, sml

I'm trying to convert a SML type to a Haskell type.

```
type Identifier = string

type 'a Environment = (Identifier * 'a) list
```

Comment: `type Identifier = string` is a case of `type alias`. In haskell, may be.. [type synonym](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_synonym) could be the closest thing!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the same code in Haskell could be

```hs
type Identifier = String

type Environment a = [(Identifier, a)]
```

Still, I would recommend to use `newtype`s to increase type safety, like in

```hs
newtype Identifier = Identifier String

newtype Environment a = Environment [(Identifier, a)]
```